# In java, what's the relationship between field and class?

Tags: java

Please refer to this API. The link is:

http://download.carrot2.org/stable/javadoc/org/carrot2/text/preprocessing/pipeline/CompletePreprocessingPipeline.html

```
Class CompletePreprocessingPipeline

Field Summary
 DocumentAssigner   documentAssigner
          Document assigner used by the algorithm, contains bindable attributes.
```

Then I found some example using completePreprocessingPipeline this way

```
completePreprocessingPipeline().documentAssigner()exactPhraseAssignment(true)
```

I do not understand the relationship between "completePreprocessingPipeline" and "documentAssigner" in terms of "field vs.class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class contains fields. All instance of that class have those fields.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

In the first example, The Bicycle class has three fields cadence, dear and speed.

This is standard Java code structure, nothing special about it.  I suggest you learn some Java and the Javadocs may make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your example must be from some other language.  Maybe a scripting language that can run on the JVM or see Java libraries.

What might be true in java:

```
CompletePreprocessingPipeline completePreprocessingPipeline = new CompletePreprocessingPipeline();
completePreprocessingPipeline.documentAssigner.exactPhraseAssignment = true;
```

You instantiate a class, and get an object.  Then you can refer to fields in the object, if the field modifier allows it (if it were `public` for example)

Answer (score 0):

A field is a member variable of a class.  The *type* of the field may indeed be another class.

In this case their appears to be a "getter method" `.documentAssigner()` which returns the `documentAssigner` field, which is of the type `DocumentAssigner`.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand the relationship
>   between
>   "completePreprocessingPipeline" and
>   "documentAssigner" in terms of "field
>   vs.class".

That's because your question doesn't make sense. Both completePreprocessingPipeline() and documentAssigner() are *methods.* No fields at all in that code. Ad there is a missing '.'.